# Detect the path robot can take between crop rows

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a problem where i need to find the path the robot can take without hitting any crop rows.[Raw Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VelV1.jpg)

My initial approach was to convert this into birds eye view and then use canny and skeletonize techniques.Then I applied Hough transform to come up with the crop rows.This works well when the rows are straight but if i rotate the image by 45 degrees I couldn't find any rows with Hough transform.So I decided to use another approach.

First I only selected the green  region and applied morphological filters to remove small branches which come out

```
img = cv2.imread('''')
min_green2 = np.array([45, 50, 50])
max_green2 = np.array([75, 250, 250])
image_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
image_blur_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image_blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
image_green = cv2.inRange(image_blur_hsv, min_red2, max_red2)
se1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,7))
se2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(image_green, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, se1)
```

I ended up with this[Final_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjYOk.png)

Now I want to detect the path the robot can take which is the black region.So only the first row is my region of interest and I tried different methods to draw a line in center of the row but couldn't find any help in opencv.I did manage to get a work around by splitting the image into two vertically and used cv2.fitline function to get a line joining one side of row and did the same with other side of row and finally I plotted the center line.But this is not an ideal approach and I feel like there might be some opencv functions to do it in much better way.Can some one help me with this or guide me in right way.

This is the final output I am looking for
[Final expected result with green color showing the center of path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g9c1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

So, here is my approach using numpy and scipy, which yielded this result:
[image: final image].

Without doing any bluring or morphological operations, use the Canny edge detector:

```py
edges = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200, None, 3, cv2.DIST_L2)
```

[image: edge detection]
Notice that most of the edges surround the track your robot wants to follow. Since each edge is a collection of white pixels, we could calculate a column's total intensity:

```py
normalized = cv2.normalize(edges, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
column_intensity = normalized.sum(axis=0)
```

Plotting the results, we get [image: pixel intensities]

If we were to find the minimum of the graph, then we would find the x direction, where most of the edges are avoided. But first, let's smooth the function so as to avoid some noise.

```py
# smooth function through moving average
window_size = 30
window = np.ones((window_size,)) / window_size
smoothed = np.convolve(column_intensity, window, mode="valid")
```

[image: smoothed graph]

Since there are a lot of local minima, our additional constraint is that the x-direction the robot should take is the closest to the center of the image.

```py
# find indices of local minima and select the one closest to the center
indices = scipy.signal.argrelmin(smoothed)[0]
distances = np.abs(indices - int(width / 2))
x = indices[np.argmin(distances)]
```

Now that we have the x-direction, we need to determine a y coordinate so as to estimate the angle the robot should rotate (tan(angle)=y/x). There are as many choices as there are rows in the image, which means the y coordinate needs to be manually set. If we choose a y closer to the robot, the angle will be more volatile as the robot advances. Conversely, if we choose a y that is far from the robot, then it will be less volatile but less accurate as well. That is up to you; the final image was created with a `y = 400`.

I hope this fits your needs :)